# No provider for Guard with ASP.NET Core Angular Spa project JavaScriptServices

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

**I am getting the error:**
No provider for AuthGuard!

Usually this would happen if the AuthGuard isn't registered in app.module. In this case I have it registered in app.module.shared.ts

The latest JavaScriptServices Angular template split out app.module into 3 - app.module.shared.ts, app.module.client.ts, app.module.server.ts which could be why it is acting strange.

Is there anything else that could be causing this error to happen? I believe it is only happening in this new JavaScriptServices template, not a vanilla Angular project.

Comment: Please add relevent code.

Comment: @yurzui There really isn't anything to add. The problem is directly related to the latest ASP.NET Core Angular template created using JavaScriptServices. They break out app.module into 3 separate files. It seems like the error goes away if I add the Guard as a provider to the app.module.server.ts file. Very strange.. Not sure why it wouldn't work in the app.module.shared.ts file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue with a service that I registered in app.module.shared.ts. It seems multiple instances of the service (a singleton) are created via dependency injection, which is causing the error (the error message doesn't imply this at all). 
I fixed it using info from the [NGMODULES docs on angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#core-module), by making a module that just registers the service as a provider.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from './components/shared/my.service';

@NgModule({
    providers: [MyService]
})
export class CoreModule { }
```

Then I added CoreModule to the imports in app.module.shared.ts

```
imports: [CoreModule]
```

Although it does fix the "No Provider" problem, there are issues with my service which makes http calls, but that is probably not related to your question.

Comment: All of this is because of this asp.net core spa Angular template? I also ran into another issue where localStorage is undefined since the asp.netcore project processes on the server. This is becoming a real pain. I am debating on whether to stick with vanilla Angular for my UI.

Comment: @BlakeRivell I'm getting similar issues with localstorage. Did you get to the bottom of it?

Comment: @mjo I don't know how you reach to this conclusion in angularspa project, but this is what I wanted for my services..